# Persisting java class in mysql with transaction rollback support

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 `@Entity` classes mapped to 3 tables in my database. The entity classes are

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "gbi_user" )
public class UserModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "u_id" )
private Long id;

@Column( name = "u_fname" )
private String firstName;

@Column( name = "u_lname" )
private String lastName;

//getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table( name = "gbi_reachable_address" )
public class AddressModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "ra_id" )
private Long id;

 @Column( name = "ra_city" )
private String city;
 @Column( name = "ra_zip" )
private Integer zip;

// getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table( name = "gbi_user_to_address" )
public class UserToAddress {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "uta_id" )
private Long id;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "uta_frn_user_id", referencedColumnName = "u_id" )
private UserModel user;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "uta_frn_add_id", referencedColumnName = "ra_id" )
private AddressModel address;
//getters and setters
}
```

In my code, I am first saving `UserModel` class to database using jpa's `save()`. Then, I am saving `AddressModel` class to database. Finally, I am saving `UserToAddress` class to database. It is working fine. But, If some exception arises while saving `UserToAddress` class, still `UserModel` and `AddressModel` will be saved in the database. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that all of the persistence is done within the context of a transaction. If you're using Spring then I'd highly suggest reviewing Spring's documentation regarding Transaction Management. Specifically looking at the `@Transactional` annotation.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-intro

A common approach would be to have an `@Service` class with a method marked as `@Transactional` and in that method you would do all necessary work to persist all entities that should share that transaction context.